# How to create a complex mulit partition array with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array with 96 price values called `price_array` and would like to have a 4 dimensional array with the following characteristics for each dimesions:

1. The first dimension quantifies the number of partitions `price_array` should have. The first entry just means, the whole array is just treated as a whole. For the second entry means that the `price_array` is divided into 2 parts, the 3rd entry means that`price_array` is divided into 3 parts. Here there should be 4 entries
2. The second dimension pinpoints of the specific partition of the data from `price_array`. Here there should be also 4 entries per entry from dimension 1. The first entry (for each entry of dimension 1) should specify which part of the partition it is referrring to. For the entry 1 of the first dimension there is only 1 partition which includes all the values. So here the other entries should of this dimension (2 nd dimension) should have the value -1. For the second entry of the first dimension there should be 2 partitions in this dimensionality. The first entry of this dimension contains the first half of the prices whereas the second entry of this dimension contains the second half of the prices. For the 3rd entry of the first dimension there should be 3 partitions etc.
3. In the 3rd dimension there should be 5 entries. Each entry specifies the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th highest k values of the partition from the second dimension.
4. The forth dimension actually contains the k  highes values specified by the values of the third dimension.

Answer (score 0):

A single numpy array doesn't seem to be the more appropriate here.

Here is an alternative:

```py
import numpy as np
from collections import namedtuple

KMax = namedtuple("KMax", ["indices", "values"])

N = 96
K = 5
num_partitions = [1, 2, 3, 4]

prices = np.random.randint(0, 500, size=N)

partitions_infos = {}
for num_parts in num_partitions:
    arr = prices.reshape(num_parts, -1)

    idxs_maxs = np.argsort(arr, axis=1)[:, -K:]
    vals_maxs = np.take_along_axis(arr, idxs_maxs, axis=1)

    partitions_infos[num_parts] = KMax(indices=idxs_maxs, values=vals_maxs)
```

```
>>> partitions_infos[3].indices  # equivalent to partitions_infos[3][0]
array([[18, 21, 13, 20, 12],
       [25,  5,  6, 17, 13],
       [20, 26, 23, 11, 12]])
```

```py
>>> partitions_infos[3].values  # equivalent to partitions_infos[3][1]
array([[448, 479, 479, 479, 498],
       [464, 481, 486, 490, 490],
       [462, 472, 477, 479, 487]])
```

Comment: Thanks paime for your answer. I have to admit that I don't understand at all how to use your approach. Where is the 4-dimensional array or how can I access the equivalent values of the 4-dimensional array? In my question I described what each of the 4 dimensionas stands for. I dont see this in your solution

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your description, in which case please provide a reproducible example with small data and expected result. From what I understood, you don't really need a 4D array, with will be sparse (as indicated by the -1 values) and with a lot of duplicated entries. With what I did  `partitions_infos[num_partitions]` is a named tuple for accessing the `indices` and `values` of the `k` max values when the array is divided in `num_parititions` ; `indices` and `values` have shape `(num_partitions, k)`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I found a workaround solution by just creating the arrays separately. So I have 4 three-dimensional arrays.